# How to change the status bar text color on Ios

Tags: flutter

I am new to all this flutter thing. I searched everywhere to find a solution for this little problem.
Is there a way to change the status bar color?
Also when i use the a color like colors.blue i can see that the  quality of the text in the status bar isn't good.

Thanks

[image]

```
appBar: AppBar(
    elevation : 0.0,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      tooltip: 'Navigation menu',
      onPressed: null,
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        tooltip: 'Search',
        onPressed: null,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Take a look to see if the SystemChrome class helps... also you can choose light or dark settings in X-code.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome-class.html

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**Edit after Flutter 2.5:**

brightness is no longer used, please use systemOverlayStyle instead.

```
appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text(widget.title),
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark // or use SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
    ),
```

**Old answer:**

@Antoine
Basically you can set your theme Brightness, or you can manually override the appbar brightness using the following :

```
appBar: new AppBar(
  title: new Text(widget.title),
  brightness: Brightness.light, // or use Brightness.dark
),
```

Do note that this will only switch between white and black status text color.

`.dark` will make the status bar text **WHITE**, while `.light` will make the status bar text **BLACK**.

Maybe for a more custom color, like the comment said you can view SystemChrome class.

Comment: It should be noted that .dark will make the status bar text WHITE, while .light will make the status bar text BLACK. This confused me at first

Comment: @vikzilla this should be included in the answer.

Comment: It doesn't do anything for me

Comment: Should be using with ThemeData:
ThemeData(appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light),)

Comment: After flutter 2.5 brightness property of AppBar is deprecated.

Comment: This is depreciated now and does not work on iOS

Comment: `brightness` is deprecated. You should use: `systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,`

Answer (score 78):

When I don't use AppBar, the colour can be changed using `AnnotatedRegion`.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

...    

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
         value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,                
         child: ...,
      ),
   );
}
```

Comment: Your answer was the only one that really worked for where I have an animated SliverPersistenheader.

Answer (score 62):

For IOS and Android:

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
   statusBarColor: Colors.white, // Color for Android
   statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark // Dark == white status bar -- for IOS.
));
```

Comment: Where to write it?

Comment: @PratikButani Within the "build" function. Or you can use the widget called "AnnotatedRegion"

Comment: @PratikButani Inside the main function, where 'runApp' is.

Comment: For more clarification , color work only for android , but brightness work for IOS

Answer (score 9):

`AnnotatedRegion` helps you change status bar text color on iOS.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
...    

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
         value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,                
         child: ...,
   );
}
```

But if you have AppBar in Scaffold then only `AnnotatedRegion` won't work. Here is solution.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark, // play with this
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          brightness: Brightness.light, // play with this
        ),
        body: Container(),
     );
  }
```

Comment: In 2022, iOS 15.5, Flutter 3.0.2, it works like a charm

Answer (score 7):

**Don't use `AnnotatedRegion`**

> Apps should not enclose an AppBar with their own [AnnotatedRegion].

You should rather use:

```dart
AppBar(
  backwardsCompatibility: false,
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.orange),
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2021. Thanks. `SystemUiOverlayStyle.light` makes the status bar text and icons white, and `SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark` makes them black.

Answer (score 6):

@Antoine this problem was a headache for me. I used the statusbarColor plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor to change the status bar color to black. I then set the appbar brightness to dark because it was a dark background.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_statusbarcolor/flutter_statusbarcolor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async{

  try {
    await FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.black);
  }  catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }


  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Using Keys',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.white

    ),
    home: InputBox(),
  ));
}

class InputBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputBoxState createState() => _InputBoxState();
}

class _InputBoxState extends State<InputBox> {
  bool loggedIn = false;
  String _email, _username, _password;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();     //a key for the state of the scaffold
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();             //a key for the state of the form

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: false,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        title: Text("Using Keys",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
            )),
        elevation: 4.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Answer for android too.

Call this if you need black text in the status bar:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
   statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // optional
));
```

and call this if you need white text in the status bar:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
   statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // optional
));
```

because *statusBarBrightness* parametr works just on iOS

Answer (score 3):

We can make the status bar dark:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
```

or light:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble having different status bar colors for different screens. I am using slivers and the brightness (which affects status bar color) can be set the same way in SliverAppBars as in normal AppBars.

```
SliverAppBar(
  brightness: Brightness.light, //or Brightness.dark
  //...
);
```

SliverAppBar's brightness, if null, defaults to AppBarTheme.brightness, ThemeData.appBarTheme or ThemeData.primaryColorBrightness in that order if any of them are null.

Example for setting AppBarTheme.brightness:

```
MaterialApp(
  //...
  theme: ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.dark),
  ),
  //...
);
```

Comment: I'm struggling with different status bar text colour on different screens, can you explain a bit more about how you got it to work please? I set the home to have black text, second screen to have white text and that works. But going back home retains the white text unfortunately.

Comment: 'brightness' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This property is no longer used, please use systemOverlayStyle instead.