# changing status bar color works for some pages only

Tags: dart, flutter

am trying to change the status bar color of my app to dark

i have followed this [How to change status bar color in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter)

and did this:

```
   SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
```

but for some reason it works only for some pages and the others will still be white!!

for example this page:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final theme = Theme.of(context).copyWith(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.red);
  Animation opacityAnimation =
  Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(animationController);
  return new Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: new Theme(
    data: theme,
    child: new Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        drawer: globals.drawer(context),
        appBar: new AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              CustomFont.burger,
              color: Color(0xff474747),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
            },
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 0.0,
          bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Container(
                color: Color(0xff2CB57D),
                height: 0.20,
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.20)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: new Image.asset(
            'assets/appbar-icon.png',
            width: 55.0,
            height: 27.0,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                CustomFont.home,
                color: Color(0xff474747),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                globals.goToHome(context);
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
        body: ......
  ),
);
}
```

the color of this page is always white no matter if i changed or not!

why is this happening? and how to solve it?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't call `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle`. You probably need to set it on each page.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer where shall i put it exactly? under   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
?

Comment: I'd try that, yes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i asked because i already did this but it didn't work :(

Comment: I'd check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle+ if there are any related issues/questions/answers.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ok please

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no news?