# Icon's color in status bar (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working with FLUTTER and the Design refers to black color for the status bar 
and the icon's color of the status bar must be white
so how can I change statusbar icon's color in flutter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter

Comment: i need to change statusbar  Icon's Color not status bar color

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue in Android 10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170915/cant-change-the-status-bar-icon-brightness-in-flutter-app

Answer (score 3):

To change the `icon` to white try the following inside the `build` method:

```
import 'package:flutter_statusbarcolor/flutter_statusbarcolor.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.white);
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(true);
...
}
```

The method `setStatusBarWhiteForeground` will change the color of the text and icon to white if it is set to true otherwise the color will be black.

more information here:
https://github.com/mchome/flutter_statusbarcolor/blob/master/lib/flutter_statusbarcolor.dart#L29

Answer (score 3):

Add the Snippet below to your `main.dart`. `setSystemUIOverlayStyle` allows one to change System overlay styles if any. This will do the job globally in your app.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));
```

This will give you the effect below(iOS & Android). Play around with the properties in `SystemUiOverlayStyle` to get what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Use `AppBar.systemOverlayStyle`:

```dart
AppBar(
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For iOS: (light icons)
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For Android: (dark icons)
    statusBarColor: ...,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that there are two options. I was trying to do that for almost half an hour with no success. It happens that I was setting iOS and testing on an android device. T_T

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet in `lib/main.dart` file.

```
        class App extends StatelessWidget {
          // This widget is the root of your application.
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
            // This code changes background color and icon color of status bar
            SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
              // statusBarColor is used to set Status bar color in Android devices.
              statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        
              // To make Status bar icons color white in Android devices.
              statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        
              // statusBarBrightness is used to set Status bar icon color in iOS.
              statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
              // Here light means dark icon color for Status bar.
            ));
        
            // material app widget
            return MaterialApp(
        
              // Status bar color
              theme: ThemeData(
                appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                  // Brightness.dark will show white color icon
                  brightness: Brightness.dark,
                ),
              ),
        
              color: Colors.white,
        
              title: 'App',
        
              home: Scaffold(),
            );
          }
        }
```

This [link](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-flutter) will be helpful to you too.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

From Flutter 2.4 onwards, you have to set the style directly, so :

```
AppBar(
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
)
```

This code works for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but for those who face the same issue

Add the following code to `main.dart` in the `MaterialApp()` theme property

```
MaterialApp(
       theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
                  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For iOS: (dark icons)
                  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For Android(M and greater): (dark icons)
                ))),
);
```

Noting that `Brightness.dark` provide dark icons and that's suitable for white background in black background case of course `Brightness.light`

> Set to [Brightness.light], the system bar icons are white.

> Set to [Brightness.dark], the system bar icons are black.

That will work globally in your app

If you want it for a specific page, there's a property in `AppBar()` called `systemOverlayStyle:`
copy the same code above to it

```
AppBar(
    systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
                      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For iOS: (dark icons)
                      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For Android(M and greater): (dark icons)
                    ),
),
```