# How to change status bar icon and text color in flutter based on theme been set?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, flutter, statusbar

How to update color for status bar icon without any third party plugin ?

in my theme class I have a function in which i am trying below code but not results achieved as of yet:

CODE FOR THEME AS OF NOW:

```
// custom light theme for app
  static final customLightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: notWhite,
    accentColor: Colors.amberAccent,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: notWhite,
    primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
      title: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black
      ),

    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      elevation: 0.0,
    )
  );

  // custom dark theme for app
  static final customDarkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.black,
      accentColor: Colors.orange,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
        title: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
        ),

      ),
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),

  );
```

---

CODE FOR THEME CHANGER:

```
// set theme for the app
   setTheme(ThemeData theme) {
     _themeData = theme;

     if(_themeData == ThemeChanger.customLightTheme){
       SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
         const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
           statusBarColor: Colors.white,
           systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
           systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.black,
           systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
         ),
       );
     } else {
       SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
         const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
           statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
           systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.blue,
           systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.red,
           systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
         ),
       );
     }

     notifyListeners();
   }
```

This is not what I want as I don't want the third party solution.

[Icon's color in status bar (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974569/icons-color-in-status-bar-flutter)

currently I am getting black icons in white / light theme and also black icons ( which should be white icons ) in dark / black theme on theme change. rest is all working well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change status bar color in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set the status bar theme by calling the `setSystemUIOverlayStyle` with required theme.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
```

or

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You can specify your own properties like,

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white
));
```

Check for available properties [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlayStyle-class.html).

---

*Note: For `light` theme of app, use `dark` overlay and vice versa. Also make sure you `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`*

Hope that helps!

Comment: by the way what if i want to modify the colors in setSystemUIOverlayStyle. my above code did not worked as you can see i tried playing with blue and red colors.

Comment: So I should remove the const word and just use the rest ? Well will try it tomorrow and see if it works 

Comment: For newbie, The question is where to write?

Comment: all of these answers and I still cant see the icons they never change colour.

Comment: No longer work for latest flutter now, also you should provide a automatically inverse based on the background option

Answer (score 22):

**Note:**
The accepted answer works if the set `SystemUiOverlayStyle` is not overwritten by other widgets like `AppBar`.

## Update

Since many people have this question, adding an answer covering all the cases I can think of.

For all the cases, use the `systemOverlayStyle` as appropriate.

#### Light Theme

```
SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
```

[image: Light]

#### Dark Theme

```
SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark
```

[image: Dark]

#### Custom

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarColor: Color(0xFF000000),
  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  systemNavigationBarDividerColor: null,
  statusBarColor: Color(0xFFD59898),
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
));
```

[image: Custom Status bar]

[image: Custom Nav bar]

Override only the required attributes. The First 3 are for the navigation bar and the remaining 3 are for the status bar.

1. Default case
   A constant system overlay style throughout the app without app bars and other widgets which interfere with the system UI overlay style.

Add this code to the **root widget of the app** inside the `build` method.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
```

2. App with a constant system overlay style
   A constant theme throughout the app with app bars.

If there are screens without an app bar, add the code given in option 1 and then add this as well.

```
MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        ),
    ),
),
```

3. App with App bars with different system overlay styles
   Each app bar has a different system overlay style.

   appBar: AppBar(
   title: const Text('Title text'),
   systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
   )

### Old answer for version below `2.4.0-0.0`.

`brightness` attribute is deprecated in `AppBar`.

> This feature was deprecated after v2.4.0-0.0.pre

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Title text'),
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
),
```

Use `Brightness.light` or `Brightness.dark` as required.

Comment: Its deprecated in flutter v2.5

Comment: @SoloWolf93, updated the answer 

Comment: The OP's question is how to change the status bar icons based on the theme set, this answer doesn't answer that at all

Answer (score 5):

#### Update (Flutter 2.4.0)

*Don't use `AnnotatedRegion` or `AppBar.brightness` as they are deprecated, use this instead:*

- **Less customizations:**

  ```dart
  AppBar(
    systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark, // Both iOS and Android (dark icons)
  )
  ```
- **More customizations:**

  ```
  AppBar(
    systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light, // For iOS: (dark icons)
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For Android: (dark icons)
      statusBarColor: ...,
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: `AnnotatedRegion` deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to set the color of the statusbaricons in particular but for me It worked to set the property `systemStatusBarContrastEnforced` to `true`.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: true,
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer to changing theme did not work for me but I use this. I know both are the same things but in this way, we can work with colour and Icons theme as well.

```
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
            SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                statusBarColor: Color(0xFFdde6e8),
                statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark),
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

To Change the status bar icon color (to white).

Add this **SystemChrome...** to your **void main()**. Before this don't forget to `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`.

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

After this, if you are using `Scaffold()` for a screen/page, then in the **AppBar()**, add this line `brightness: Brightness.dark,` like this,

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
```

Then done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the theme builder for entire app there is new way to change the brightness (icons color) to be white or black as follow

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      builder: (context, navigator) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: AppColors.primary,
              accentColor: AppColors.accent,
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(systemOverlayStyle: 
       SystemUiOverlayStyle.light) ,//this is new way to change icons color of status bar
              fontFamily: 'Poppins'
          ),
          child: navigator,
        );
      },
      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things we do not merge in AppBar.

1. backgroundColor
2. SystemUiOverlayStyle

check the below code. Use **backgroundColor** OR **systemOverlayStyle**

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('TEXT_HERE'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using AppBar there's `brightness` property. You can set the brightness property to `dark` so the icons of status bar will get white.

```dart
AppBar(
    brightness: Brightness.dark
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it looks more or less like a duplicate of @Abhimanyu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66942220/7451109).

Answer (score -1):

I found that the best way to do this is via AppBar widget.
If you are not using appbar on exact screen, you can achieve this with implementing dummy transparent appbar:

```dart
Scaffold(
      // critical to imitate appbar absence
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      
      appBar: AppBar(
        // setup your style here
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        toolbarHeight: 0.0,
      ),
      body: ...,
)
```