# Change status bar icons color Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to change these icons color in IOS?

[image: IOS Status bar Icons]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change status bar icon and text color in flutter based on theme been set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995748/how-to-change-status-bar-icon-and-text-color-in-flutter-based-on-theme-been-set)

Comment: It works only for android.

Comment: You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52489458/10157127)

Comment: Still nothing, I will be putting this in github I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SystemChrome

```
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
   statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light, // For iOS: (dark icons)
   statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For Android: (dark icons)
  ),
```

Comment: Works only on android, am looking for a solution for ios devices.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to change the appearance of the status bar. If the application has an AppBar, you can set the `backgroundColor` and brightness arguments of the AppBar to change the style. If the application doesn't have an AppBar, you can use `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` or `AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>`

Comment: Tried these solutions but still can't figure out a way to change it for ios, it can be changed when I do have an AppBar but in this case am trying not to use appbars in the project.