# Can't change the status bar Icon Brightness in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In main.dart

```
void main() {
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0), //top bar color
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //top bar icons
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black, //bottom bar color
  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light, //bottom bar icons
),
);
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    //primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(113, 201, 206, 1),
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      ),
      title: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
      body1: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  home: Test(),
  routes: {
    MainScreen.routeName: (context) => MainScreen(),
  },
);
}
}
```

I am using the above code to change the color of the status bar, `statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark` has no effect.
It becomes black but after a few seconds it switches back to `Brightness.light'.
What's wrong?

Running on Android Emulator.
I don't want to have `appBar` int the `Test()` widget.

Comment: your code is perfect but try to use your above code in **MyApp** class before returning scaffold

Comment: Are you trying on the emulator ? or a real device. If emulator then which android or apple. This will only work on android.

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 8):

That's because you're not explicitly changing `AppBar`'s `brightness` in your `Test` page. Run this code and see the difference:

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0), //top bar color
       // statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // don't use this
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp2());
}

class MyApp2 extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("AppBar"),
          brightness: Brightness.light, // use this instead
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output-1 (Brightness.dark):**

[image]

**Output-2 (Brightness.light):**

[image]

Comment: I don't have `appBar` in my `test` widget. but still it's not working.!

Comment: yours, not working, `Test` widget is very complex widget with no `appBar`, And one more thing initially `Brightness.light` is set but when i set `PrimaryColor` in root of the app, then it changes to `Brightnesss.dark` and doesn't change.

Comment: I am not sure why my solution didn't work, it is very simple and straightforward, please don't make any changes in it, simply put it and run it. It will work.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad, Does this solution only works with the App bar included ? What if we don't need an app bar ?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying something similar, but the status bar was transparent instead of blue. I added the following and it worked:

```
theme: ThemeData(
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
```

Answer (score 0):

@CopsOnRoad's answer worked for me with a little twist. You see sometimes the `Brightness` class has this funny way of creating a confusion. Meaning, if you want to make the status bar icons color white, you have to go with `Brightness.dark` instead of `Brightness.light`. I did exactly that and boom! It started working. Just take @CopsOnRoad's answer and change `light` to `dark`. At leas that is what worked for me.
I concluded that in this particular case, setting `Brightness.light` means "change the status bar icons' color to some color that is suitable for light colored status bar (White or similar color status bar background) which means that the system will set the icons to black in order for the user to be able to see the icons.
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is systemNavigationBarColor making statusBarIconBrightness no effect.