# hown to get i white statusbar color and black icon in flutter

Tags: flutter

friend !!..
I wanted a transparent status bar in the flutter with black icons. but it shows me a transparent status bar but the icons are not black...
like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQE5o.png)

my code...

```
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
        statusBarColor: Colors.white,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarBrightness:Brightness.dark) 
    );
```

this is error..

```
W/DynamiteModule(22475): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
D/ConnectivityManager(22475): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10508, CallingPid : 22475
I/DynamiteModule(22475): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(22475): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/ConnectivityManager(22475): unregisterNetworkCallback; CallingUid : 10508, CallingPid : 22475
D/ConnectivityManager(22475): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10508, CallingPid : 22475
D/ConnectivityManager(22475): unregisterNetworkCallback; CallingUid : 10508, CallingPid : 22475
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(22475): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
I/ViewRootImpl@9fa911b[MainActivity](22475): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,720,1600) new=(0,0,720,1600) req=(720,1600)0 dur=11 res=0x1 s={true 537913692160} ch=false
I/ViewRootImpl@9fa911b[MainActivity](22475): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,720,1600) new=(0,0,720,1600) req=(720,1600)0 dur=11 res=0x1 s={true 537913692160} ch=false
```

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974569/icons-color-in-status-bar-flutter/61231594) solution - try to use `SystemUiOverlayStyle` instead of `SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark`.

Comment: see my edited question and it also happens in SystemUiOverlayStyle