# Flutter build failed after adding dependency

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Build fails after I've tried to install [flutter_statusbarcolor](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor#-readme-tab-) package. Everything was ok before I did it, I am using Mac and XCode simulator. I just want to change color of status bar. [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032540/5246900) doesn't work.

```
$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            1,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build descriptionerror: /Users/Bob/Documents/Projects/Flutter/gp/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file
    'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')error:
    /Users/Bob/Documents/Projects/Flutter/gp/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target
    'Runner' from project 'Runner')error: /Users/Bob/Documents/Projects/Flutter/gp/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support
    Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')error: /Users/Bob/Documents/Projects/Flutter/gp/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find
    included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')error:
    /Users/Bob/Documents/Projects/Flutter/gp/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target
    'Runner' from project 'Runner')error: /Users/Bob/Documents/Projects/Flutter/gp/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support
    Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

[Then](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24733#issuecomment-441599240) I removed this package from dependencies and all files in `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/` directory. But Flutter still throws the same error. How to restore my app and change color for status bar natively?

Comment: which version of dependence do you use?

Comment: As it mensioned in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor#-installing-tab-) `flutter_statusbarcolor: ^0.2.2`

Comment: try with older version like 0.2.0

Answer (score 3):

This helped me:

> Go to ios dir and type `pod install`

Reference: https://github.com/X-Wei/flutter_catalog/issues/26#issuecomment-548923989

Answer (score 1):

add

```
path_provider: 1.6.1
```

to **pubspec.yaml** and then
then

```
flutter pub get
```