# How to change the time and Phone Icons like wifi color when appbar background is changed to white

Tags: flutter

I changed the background color of the appBar in one of my screens. It's now white, but the device time display and icons like the wifi icon don't show. How can I change the color of these device icons?

This is what I have now:
[image]

This is what I want to achieve
[image]

Here is my appBar code

```
 child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: KjobbersAppTheme.white,
            appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0.0,
              textTheme: TextTheme(
                  title: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 20.0,
              )),
              backgroundColor: KjobbersAppTheme.white,
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  color: AppTheme.grey,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              ),
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey, size: 20),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change status bar color in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `brightness` property of the `AppBar` to `Brightness.light`. It will change all the status bar icons to a darker color.

**Example-**

```
AppBar(
  brightness: Barightness.light,
  //Rest of your code will remain same
)
```

Alternatively, if the `AppBar` has a dark `backgroundColor`, you can set it to `Brightness.dark`, to force the `AppBar` to have light colored icons.