# flutter:when my appbar doesn t exist ,how can I control my StatusBar text color or brightness

Tags: flutter

I have tried like this:

```
return Semantics(
  explicitChildNodes: true,
  container: true,
  child: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: widget.statusBarTextIsBlack
        ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark
        : SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
    child: Semantics(
      explicitChildNodes: true,
      child: MyPage(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

or do this in func build

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
));
```

but it useless.I dont know how to solve it.............

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52492805/7924072 this may help you.  Use it FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.white);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your scaffold with **SafeArea**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: CustomColors.background, //navigation bar color
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      statusBarColor: CustomColors.background, // status bar color
    ));
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
```

Comment: This is the only way without appbar

Comment: emm what if i want to use CupertinoNavigationBar?How can i do with it??

Comment: if you use **CupertinoNavigationBar** then no need to wrap in **SafeArea**. because it will take **StatusBar** color which you have given to **CupertinoNavigationBar**

Comment: so how can I change my StatusBar brightness when i use CupertinoNavigationBar? .......

Comment: inside your **initState()** or inside **widget build** before **return** statement.. see my updated Answer