# How to change the status bar icons and text color to black in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using white background for App Bar in flutter and how can I change the status bar icon colors to black,

I am using this code to change the status bar color,

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white,
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
));
```

Answer (score 6):

**Flutter 2.4.0+ UPDATE**

Since flutter 2.4.0 `brightness: Brightness.dark` is deprecated.

It has been replaced by `systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark`

How to use:

`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

```
appBar: AppBar(
    systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
    elevation: 0.0,
),
```

Set `SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark` if you want black icons.

Set `SystemUiOverlayStyle.light` if you want white icons.

Answer (score 4):

##### Hi, in my project, I use the following (use `Brightness` was obsolete)

###### Without AppBar:

- 

```
return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
            //Set status bar icon color
            value: your_condition
                ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
                    statusBarColor: your_color,
                    //statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
                  )
                : SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
                    statusBarColor: your_color,
                    //statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
                  ),
            child: your_widget);
```

###### With AppBar:

```
return AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    systemOverlayStyle: your_condition ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark : SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
    backgroundColor: your_color,
);
```

- You can use a combination of the two methods above to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set to `brightness` in AppBar if you are using one. Eg.

```
appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
),
```

You can checkout detailed answer here: [How to change status bar color in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter)