# How can I make notification bar dark in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter and I want to make this grey notification bar black also time and other icons should be white for just one page not for all app I have tried the library below but it is not working for me. Is there any solution for this?

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor

[image]

Comment: Kotlin? Is your issue Flutter or Android?

Comment: Flutter @MarianoZorrilla

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter#comment110488268_53032540

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change status bar color in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter)

Answer (score -1):

SystemUiOverlayStyle uiConfig = SystemUiOverlayStyle(
statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
statusBarColor: (Color),
);