# Why is the AppBar background color not completely white on Android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

I set `Scaffold` `appBar:` to `null`, but the Appbar is grey not white.

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: null,
    body: .......
);
```

[image: AppBar]

And I also set AppBar color to white but result is same as `null`.

How can I make Appbar color be white?
Set null is not enough?

Below image is the AppBar of Google Play Store.

[image: Play Store AppBar]

Comment: You can find the solution in this link.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AppBar`'s `systemOverlayStyle` property:

```
AppBar(
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.white),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

To hide status bar or disable notification bar in Android, IT admins must perform the following two steps:

1.Add devices to Kiosk Mode
2.Hide notification bar

1.Add device to Kiosk Mode
1_ On the MDM console, create an Android profile by navigating to Device Mgmt -> Profiles -> New Profile -> Android.
2_ Specify a name and description before creating the profile.
3_ From the left pane, select Kiosk for creating a Kiosk Mode profile
4_ Select Single App if you want to run only one app on the device and Multi-app for running multiple apps on the devices
5_ Enter the name of the app(s) that need to be provisioned in Kiosk.
How to hide status bar on Android devices?
To hide or disable the status and notification bar on Android devices while enabling Kiosk Mode, follow the steps given below:

1_ Select the Kiosk Mode profile to which you've added the apps to be provisioned in Kiosk Mode.
2_ Navigate to Device Restrictions to disable the status bar in Android devices.
3_ Restrict the Status Bar option to disable the status bar on the device. By default the Status Bar expansion option is restricted, which disables the notification bar.
You can also optionally disable the Task Bar to prevent users from accessing the default launcher or exiting Kiosk.
Click on Save to save the profile. Distribute the profile to Groups or devices based on your requirements