# How to change status bar color of native splash screen in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to change Status bar color in android and ios Native splash screen according to  Dark mode and Light mode in mobile.
Native splash screen generated using `flutter_native_splash : ^2.2.0+1`

I tried below thing but didn't work in android in res/night/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

[image: splash screen screenshots]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter

Comment: No, I am trying to change color of Native splash screen.

Comment: It changes for whole app. I need only for native splash screen in app

Comment: I used Colorfulsafearea for rest of that screens

Comment: Please write your own sources that are minimally executable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by adding below code in values/styles.xml and values-night/styles.xml in res folder:

```
  <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Default native splash screen is not full screen. To enable full screen you need to use `fullscreen: true` on your yaml file.

```yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  fullscreen: true
```

To hide the notification bar, use the fullscreen parameter.  Has no effect in web since web has no notification bar.
Defaults to false.

NOTE: Unlike Android, iOS will not automatically show the notification bar when the app loads.
To show the notification bar, add the following code to your Flutter app:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
       SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

More and ref on [`flutter_native_splash`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#1-setting-the-splash-screen)

Comment: it's work but for only first time whenever app restarted it's again shows black status bar

Comment: make sure to quit the app properly, else it will start from `onResume`  lifecycle instead of `onCreate` lifecycle.