# Change navigation bottom bar color on splash screen flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

[image: Splash Screen]

How change the navigation bar color of the splash screen ? I'm using `flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.7`

I want the status bar color to be like color #e8472d

Comment: how is it possible that your splash screen shows a navbar?
if the navbar already appears, I think the flutter app has finished initilize   and move to your home screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change status bar color of native splash screen in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72471785/how-to-change-status-bar-color-of-native-splash-screen-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `SystemUiOverlayStyle` using the default constructor. The color of the system nav bar is defined there. But to avoid setting a lot of null values, use the `copyWith` method to update the values from an existing light/dark theme.

```
const mySystemTheme= SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
 .copyWith(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.red);
```

You can imperatively set the system nav color using the `SystemChrome` static methods.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUiOverlayStyle(mySystemTheme);
```