# Flutter enable solid status bar (on Android)

Tags: android, flutter, layout, statusbar

As you can see, my default app status bar is transparent.

**I want it to be solid, and the layout to be between the status bar and the bottom nav bar.**

[image]

I'm using `Scaffold` inside `MaterialApp`:

```
MaterialApp(
  body:
    Scaffold(
      body:
      ...
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: If you are looking for changing status Bar color follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/52489458/10157127

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for the "SafeArea" solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Scaffold`'s body with `SafeArea` widget.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  body: SafeArea(
       child: Scaffold(
```

Comment: Do you know why is the app is not "safe" by default? I think it's the first time I need to use `SafeArea`

Comment: Decided by flutter, all I can say.  Also, you can scaffold source code, like some cases like web and windows we aren't using safeArea,