# Change systemOverlay color flutter

Tags: flutter

Can the background color of system icons be changed? I know I can change icon color, but I can't find any option to change the background color.
See image for clarification.

[image]

Comment: Does [How to change status bar color in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52489458/10157127) answer your question

Comment: yes it does, thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this by specifying the `systemOverlayStyle` inside the `appBar`

```
AppBar(
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.green, //  Add your color here
  ),
)
```